# Using gulp-sftp to upload only changed files

Tags: node.js, sftp, gulp, gulp-watch

I have the following task in gulp:

```
gulp.task('sync-frontend', /*['build-frontend'],*/ function()
{

    if(config.layout.frontend.syncOnBuild)
        return gulp
            .src(config.layout.frontend.distDir + '/**')
            .pipe(changed(config.layout.frontend.distDir, {hasChanged: changed.compareSha1Digest}))
            //.pipe(debug())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.layout.frontend.distDir))
            .pipe(sftp
            ({

                host: config.sftp.host,
                port: config.sftp.port,
                user: config.sftp.user,
                pass: config.sftp.pass,
                remotePath: (config.layout.frontend.remotePath ? config.layout.frontend.remotePath : config.sftp.remotePath )

            }));

});
```

The config.layout.frontend.distDir value is 'httpdocs'.

The problem is that no files are being uploaded, no matter if they are changed or not (I already tried to leave hasChange option of gulp-changed in the default. I always get the following output:

```
[20:45:52] Using gulpfile /Storage/Portable/Sync/Projects/Prataria/web-prataria/gulpfile.js
[20:45:52] Starting 'sync-frontend'...
[20:45:52] gulp-sftp: No files uploaded
[20:45:52] Finished 'sync-frontend' after 503 ms
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and found the formatting on the gulp.src needed to be prefixed with the `./` to find the correct folder.  So try `./httpdocs` as your value for `config.layout.frontend.distDir`.

Answer (score 0):

You can gulp-sftp together with another library like "gulp-changed" or "gulp-watch".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [vinyl-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp) library. The `newer` function can be utilized to only upload newer files. The library's README even includes a sample Gulp task which shows this in action:

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

gulp.task( 'deploy', function () {

    var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'mywebsite.tld',
        user:     'me',
        password: 'mypass',
        parallel: 10,
        log:      gutil.log
    } );

    var globs = [
        'src/**',
        'css/**',
        'js/**',
        'fonts/**',
        'index.html'
    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance

    return gulp.src( globs, { base: '.', buffer: false } )
        .pipe( conn.newer( '/public_html' ) ) // only upload newer files
        .pipe( conn.dest( '/public_html' ) );

} );
```

Comment: VinylFTP is pretty ok until you need to upload via SFTP (port 22), which VinylFTP cannot handle.